# mysql select 2 days ago 's row and convert it to columns based on date column

Tags: mysql

i have some data like below.

```
date                   metric  value
2011-05-18 09:17:25     m1        10
2011-05-18 09:17:25     m2        10
2011-05-17 09:17:25     m1        30
2011-05-17 09:17:25     m2        40
2011-05-16 09:17:25     m1        50
2011-05-16 09:17:25     m2        60
2011-05-15 09:17:25     m1        40
2011-05-15 09:17:25     m2        30
lost of more...
```

i want  merge two day ago's  row  to columns  as  looks like  below.

```
 date                    m1  m2   offsetdays  offset_date           m1    m2   
 2011-05-18 09:17:25     10  10       2       2011-05-16 09:17:25     50    60         
 2011-05-17 09:17:25     30  40       2       2011-05-15 09:17:25     40    30
```

Comment: What is `o_m1`? How did you compute that?

Comment: @Yusuf Hassan:   i guess mysql columns  name can not be duplicate, so..